# Subtree repository and main repository both inlcude same file. Is that normal git behaviour?

Tags: git, git-subtree

When using git subtree, is it normal that the files reside in both the subtree repo and the main repo?

- First, I added a remote `git remote add -f somename https://tmee@bitbucket.org/ssatr/somename.git`
- added a new file @ /somename/test.txt and then did a `git add . && git commit "added test file"`
- Then I pushed to the subtree `git subtree push --prefix somename somename master`  (this adds the file in the subtree repo)
- However when I later did a `git push` on the main repo, the added
  file also shows up on the main repo.

Is this normal behaviour?

Comment: Yes - why wouldn't it be? A subtree just means: *Take all the existing commits. Make new commits from them; in the new commits, use a subset of all the files, instead of all the files.* If the file is in both the large set (it must be, by definition) *and* the subset (it may or may not be, depending on the chosen subset), it will either be in just the main repo, or in both that repo *and* the sub-repo formed by taking the subset.

Comment: Your comment is confusing. Subtree could also mean that code only is attached to the main set as a subtree.

Comment: It *could* mean that, perhaps, if Git were different. But Git is the way Git is, so it can't mean that. Read [the `git subtree` documentation](https://manpages.debian.org/testing/git-man/git-subtree.1.en.html) (note that `git subtree` is no longer a normal part of Git, and is now just an add-on) and pay close attention to where `git subtree push` is described as meaning `git subtree split` followed by a push; then read the section on `git subtree split`.